# Using conditionals to #define

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, constants, c-preprocessor

I'm trying to define the a constant, HEIGHT_WINDOW, but I want it to depend on whether the user is running on an iPhone 4 or an iPhone 5. I already have a way to check what iPhone the user is on.

Is there a way I can do something like:

```
if (//is running on iPhone 4) {
    #define HEIGHT_WINDOW 300
} else {
    #define HEIGHT_WINDOW 400
}
```

If anyone has any tips I would greatly appreciate it - again I just want to #define something based on whether the user is running on an iPhone 4 or iPhone 5.

Comment: If you can make `HEIGHT_WINDOW` a variable instead of a macro then you can just do `HEIGHT_WINDOW = 300` inside the if block.

Comment: You can't use `#define` for this since you need a runtime check, not a compile time check.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this at compile time, since the decision has to be done at runtime, so trying to use preprocessor macros doesn't even make sense. Use a normal variable instead:

```
double windowHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 500
                    ? 400
                    : 300;
```

Comment: Thank you sir for the input, but it seems like there is a viable solution, given by Mr. Mayank Jain.

    #define HEIGHT_WINDOW ( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 500? 400 : 300)

I tried this and it does indeed work. With all due respect, I don't quite understand what you mean? I'm a bit of a beginner so I have no idea what you mean when you say compile time and runtime and preprocessor macros.

Comment: @RaymondChan You really have no idea, and you should in fact not have accepted that answer, because it does not answer your question. It's not that you can't `#define` a macro to access the screen height conveniently - it's just that you can't use `#ifdef` and `#if` (preprocessor conditionals) for checking if the code runs on an iPhone 5. The code is compiled once. The macros are resolved at compile-time. But the code then can run on any device - regardless of how, how many times, when and where it was compiled. So the preprocessor has no clue about the runtime. And quite frankly, if you don't

Comment: @RaymondChan (cont) understand this, you should not yet be writing iOS applications, but you should head over to you local library, grab K&R C and read and understand it before even touching the iOS SDK at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if (result.height==480)
        {
           NSLog(@"iPhone 4 or 4s");
        }
        if (result.height==568)
        {
             NSLog(@"iPhone 5");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks sir, for the input. I already know how to find out whether the user is on an iPhone 4 or an iPhone 5. I was looking more so for something like Mr. Mayank Jain's answer

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a variable instead of a constant for this. Macros don't work this way.

```
int HEIGHT_WINDOW;
if (//is running on iPhone 4) {
    HEIGHT_WINDOW = 300
} else {
    HEIGHT_WINDOW = 400
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, for the input. But Mr. Mayank Jain has offered a great solution, and I think it does work so far:


#define HEIGHT_WINDOW ( [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 500? 400 : 300)

Comment: @RaymondChan that would work too.. It is a little bit inefficient since it will check every time, instead of just once, but might not be much of a hit if not checked too often.. Also, there is no need for so much formality :)

Answer (score -1):

I have done this alot of times in my code and it definitely works.

```
#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )

if(!IS_IPHONE_5)
{
    [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y , self.view.frame.size.width, 300)];
}
else
{
    [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y , self.view.frame.size.width, 400)];
}
```

Comment: That macro with the exact `568` looks nasty, even when a certain epsilon is taken into account.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what this code does. Why are you setting self.view's frame?

Comment: This code first sets a macro that tests whether its iphone 5 or not. Once it is done.. you can check it anywhere and put conditions accordingly anywhere.